# Two equivalent lines evaluating to different results [bit-shifting]

Tags: c

I'm calling this code on a function so that a signed int n is set to zero, but it behaves strangely.

```
printf("n is %d \n", n);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
printf("shift1 %d \n", -1 << (32 + (~0 + 1)));
printf("shift2 %d \n", -1 << (32 + (~n + 1)));
```

prints

```
n is 0
shift1 0
shift2 -2
```

I have no idea why this is happening, since n == 0.

Comment: @cdhowie n is a signed int.

Comment: Note that left-shifting a negative integer is undefined behavior, so technically this output is allowed by the C spec.  We may be able to reason about how it behaves on your particular compiler, but we cannot reason about how it will behave generally, and therefore we cannot provide an answer.

Comment: For example, note that the output here is 0: http://ideone.com/q4sDy3 -- what answer you get may depend on a whole host of factors, and the answer could differ between runs of the same program.  UB is UB.

Comment: Unless your int on your platform is >32 bits, left shifting a signed int by 32 or more is undefined behavior, and left shifting a negative int is also undefined behavior. Your compiler might produce whatever it wants to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It behaves strangely because the behavior of the `<<` operator applied to a negative integer is undefined.  Therefore, any result is a valid result of this code.

Since the behavior is not defined, we cannot reason about it.  So we cannot really say *why* it differs, only that according to the C specification it is *allowed* to differ.

When I try it, I get zero as the result of both shifts.  (Neither of our results are more correct!  This is simply to show that the same program invoking undefined behavior can indeed produce different results on different compilers and/or architectures.)

Comment: It seems that even if we change `-1` to `1` we still have undefined behavior since the shift count is too large.

Answer (score 1):

Shifting a negative number under any circumstances, by any amount (even 0), in any direction, is always [Undefined Behavior (UB)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984).
The same for shifting a signed value such that the mathematical result cannot be stored in its type.

One cannot reason about undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the difference even after changing `-1` to `1` (with Visual Studio, in `DEBUG` configuration):

```
printf("n is %d \n", n);
printf("shift1 %d \n", 1 << (32 + (~0 + 1)));
printf("shift2 %d \n", 1 << (32 + (~n + 1)));
```

For the first line, I'm getting a [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx0bb1cy.aspx):

> warning C4293: '<<' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior

The point is that in the first case, my compiler evaluates expression at compile time and sees that the operand is too big, and in the second case - at run time.

In my case, at compile time, the expression gets evaluated to `0`, at run time - to `1`

```
int n = 0;
    mov         dword ptr [n],0

auto x = 1 << (32 + (~0 + 1));
    mov         dword ptr [x],0  

auto y = 1 << (32 + (~n + 1));
    mov         ecx,dword ptr [n]  
    not         ecx  
    add         ecx,21h  
    mov         eax,1  
    shl         eax,cl  
    mov         dword ptr [y],eax
```

In `RELEASE` mode, both results are the same.